# Running XMPP on Amazon for a chat app

Tags: python, ruby, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, xmpp

I'm building an Android IM chat app for fun. I can develop the Android stuff well but i'm not so good with the networking side so I am looking at using XMPP on AWS servers to run the actual IM side. I've looked at OpenFire and ejabberd which i could use. Does anyone have any experience with them or know a better one? I'm mostly looking for sending direct IM between friends and group IM with friends.

Answer (score 1):

Try to explore more about Amazon SQS( Simple Queuing Service) . It might come handy for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

As an employee of ProcessOne, the makers of ejabberd, I can tell you we run a lot of services over AWS, including mobile chat apps. We have industrialized our procedures.

Comment: How would you say the difficulty is of setup. As an android dev my networking skills are a bit rusty. I'm trying to create a network in which only users of this app will be able to chat through and not anyone using jabber.